# how to show combobox second value in default using C++ winapi 32?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dialog

i have problem in display a login dialogbox...
that have 2 textbox,1 combobox like username,password,domain...

1.i have setfocus in username ,that cant set

```
SetFocus(GetDlgItem(_hwnd, IDC_NAME));
```

but,it cant set when system logontime,the cursor symbol is focus that textbox,but values not get,ather i click that textbox,then only focus that textbox...
but after login other dialogbox textboxs are focused using this type of code,like

```
SetFocus(GetDlgItem(hchged, IDC_PWD));
```

2.In combobox the systemname and domain name there...every login time
system name only showed...how to change that into domain name...

note:i am using c++ win32 API dialogbox...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is incredibly difficult to understand. Based off the title, it sounds like you want to do this:

```
ComboBox_SetCurSel(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_COMBO_BOX), 1);
```

Comment: Thank u Mike...it works fine...now i have 2 doubts...1.SetFocus(GetDlgItem(_hwnd, IDC_NAME)); cant focus that textbox...2.i have three buttons in that dialogbox,                if i press enter keyword ID_OK button will work...but i want to invoke ID_MYBUTTON...how can i achieve that both?

Comment: @SanjuMonu: These sound like separate questions to me. You should ask a new question and include information about what kind of control `IDC_NAME` represents and why you think the focus is not being set and where in the code you are attempting to set the focus, etc.

Comment: :i did it...come to this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007869/how-to-invoke-a-button-using-c-win32-api-when-press-the-enter-button